# Debian Testing Suspend Problems

Tags: linux, debian, suspend

I have a rather current Debian testing installation (kernel `4.16.0-2-amd64`). Since some time, the computer immediately wakes up again after running `pm-suspend` or `dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend boolean:true`.

`dmesg` says the following:

```
...
[ 9160.045039] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[ 9160.045042] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[ 9160.395257] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 9160.396974] OOM killer disabled.
[ 9160.396974] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[ 9160.398129] Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[ 9160.401725] parport_pc 00:03: disabled
[ 9160.401788] serial 00:02: disabled
[ 9160.435110] do_IRQ: 2.36 No irq handler for vector
[ 9160.438931] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdd] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 9160.438986] sd 14:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 9160.438989] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdc] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 9160.439165] sd 16:0:0:0: [sdc] Stopping disk
[ 9160.439629] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdd] Stopping disk
[ 9160.442885] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[ 9160.443753] sd 15:0:0:0: [sdb] Stopping disk
[ 9163.750287] sd 14:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[ 9164.879231] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[ 9164.880048] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[ 9164.880077] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 9164.895152] IRQ 25: no longer affine to CPU1
[ 9164.896219] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[ 9164.919375] IRQ 26: no longer affine to CPU2
[ 9164.920453] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[ 9164.943343] IRQ 27: no longer affine to CPU3
[ 9164.944421] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline 
[ 9164.975307] IRQ 19: no longer affine to CPU4
[ 9164.975314] IRQ 28: no longer affine to CPU4
[ 9164.976400] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline 
[ 9164.999266] IRQ 16: no longer affine to CPU5
[ 9164.999331] IRQ 39: no longer affine to CPU5
[ 9164.999334] IRQ 40: no longer affine to CPU5
[ 9165.000344] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
[ 9165.023252] IRQ 18: no longer affine to CPU6
[ 9165.023259] IRQ 23: no longer affine to CPU6
[ 9165.024342] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline 
[ 9165.048334] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
[ 9165.052146] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
[ 9165.052190] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory 
[ 9165.053568] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[ 9165.053617] x86: Booting SMP configuration: 
[ 9165.053619] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[ 9165.056696]  cache: parent cpu1 should not be sleeping
[ 9165.056872] hpet: hpet3 irq 25 for MSI
[ 9165.056942] CPU1 is up
[ 9165.056963] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4 
[ 9165.059904]  cache: parent cpu2 should not be sleeping
[ 9165.060097] hpet: hpet4 irq 26 for MSI
[ 9165.060207] CPU2 is up
[ 9165.060226] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
[ 9165.063177]  cache: parent cpu3 should not be sleeping
[ 9165.063371] hpet: hpet5 irq 27 for MSI
[ 9165.063473] CPU3 is up
[ 9165.063497] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x1 
[ 9165.065922]  cache: parent cpu4 should not be sleeping
[ 9165.066113] hpet: hpet6 irq 28 for MSI
[ 9165.066235] CPU4 is up
...
```

Changing all devices to `disabled` in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` does not change this behaviour, too. What else could I try to diagnose the problem?